# Is it bad to store the underlying type of an object?

Tags: c++

If I have a class called `Node`, would it be bad, if objects of the `Node` class knew their `NodeType`, and the `NodeType` would be used to cast to a specific interface like this:

```
// NodeType

enum class NodeType : uint8_t
{
    None        = 0,
    Foo         = 1 << 0,
    Bar         = 1 << 1,
    FooBar      = 1 << 2,
    
    FooMask     = Foo | FooBar,
    BarMask     = Bar | FooBar,
};

inline constexpr uint8_t operator&(const NodeType& t_lhs, const NodeType& t_rhs)
{
    return static_cast<uint8_t>(t_lhs) & static_cast<uint8_t>(t_rhs);
}
```

```
// Base Node Class

class Node
{
public:
    virtual NodeType GetNodeType() const = 0;
};
```

```
// Interfaces

class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual ~IFoo() = default;

    virtual void FooSpecificMethod() const = 0;
};

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual ~IBar() = default;

    virtual void BarSpecificMethod() const = 0;
};
```

```
// Derived Node Classes

class FooNode : public Node, public IFoo
{
public:
    NodeType GetNodeType() const override { return NodeType::Foo; }

    void FooSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Foo.\n"; }
};

class BarNode : public Node, public IBar
{
public:
    NodeType GetNodeType() const override { return NodeType::Bar; }

    void BarSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Bar.\n"; }
};

class FooBarNode : public Node, public IFoo, public IBar
{
public:
    NodeType GetNodeType() const override { return NodeType::FooBar; }

    void FooSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Foo.\n"; }

    void BarSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Bar.\n"; }
};
```

```
// Use of NodeType and Interfaces

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> GetNodes()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes{};

    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<FooNode>());
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<FooNode>());

    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<BarNode>());

    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<FooBarNode>());
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<FooBarNode>());
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<FooBarNode>());

    return nodes;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes{ GetNodes() };
    
    for (const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        if ((node->GetNodeType() & NodeType::FooMask) != 0)
            dynamic_cast<const IFoo*>(node.get())->FooSpecificMethod();
    }

    for (const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        if ((node->GetNodeType() & NodeType::BarMask) != 0)
            dynamic_cast<const IBar*>(node.get())->BarSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

My goal is to do type specific things on objects in a polymorphic collection like in the last code snippet. Is this a bad approach? Is there any more OO approach to this?

Comment: if you need to know exact class it means you have problems with interface and roles separation. User of polymorh classes must know only interface, all details must be hidden behind implementation and be irrelevant to interface user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bad approach? Is there any more OO approach to this?

Yes. You can just `dynamic_cast` to the appropriate pointer type and check the result is not null.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes{ GetNodes() };
    
    for (const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        if (auto foo = dynamic_cast<const IFoo*>(node.get()))
            foo->FooSpecificMethod();
    }

    for (const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        if (auto bar = dynamic_cast<const IBar*>(node.get()))
            bar->BarSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

If for some reason you want to avoid `dynamic_cast`, you can add virtual functions to `Node`. This is perhaps the "most OO" way.

```
class Node
{
public:
    virtual ~Node() = default;
    virtual const IFoo * asFoo() const { return nullptr; }
    virtual const IBar * asBar() const { return nullptr; }
};

class FooNode : public Node, public IFoo
{
public:
    const IFoo* asFoo() const override { return this; }

    void FooSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Foo.\n"; }
};

class BarNode : public Node, public IBar
{
public:
    const IBar* asBar() const override { return this; }

    void BarSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Bar.\n"; }
};

class FooBarNode : public Node, public IFoo, public IBar
{
public:
    const IFoo* asFoo() const override { return this; }
    const IBar* asBar() const override { return this; }

    void FooSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Foo.\n"; }

    void BarSpecificMethod() const override { std::cout << "Bar.\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes{ GetNodes() };
    
    for (const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        if (auto foo = node->asFoo())
            foo->FooSpecificMethod();
    }

    for (const auto& node : nodes)
    {
        if (auto bar = node->asBar())
            bar->BarSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was aware of this, but didn't want to rely on having `RTTI` enabled, I wanted to make it easy to convert to `C-Style cast`s incase `dynamic_cast`s hurts my performance

Comment: @SamoChreno You need `dynamic_cast` because the interfaces are not the first base in your concrete types

Comment: Ah, I think I was wrong and you are right. I thought `dynamic_cast` behaves like a `static_cast` with an extra check, but I don't think I was right. Just tried it out with a `C-Style cast` and it doesn't work. Excuse me for my lack of knowledge.